# GEB- Select the First occurrence of the link in a column, which is having the same value

Tags: jquery, geb

I’m searching for a string in HTML page and results are displayed in the table format.
The results are displayed in the three columns. I need to select the 2nd column value which is a link.
The 2nd column always will have the value, “View as HTML” for all the records.
How can I select the 1st occurrence of “View as HTML”.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear but I will try to answer what I think you are asking.

It sounds like your NonEmptyNavigator object is matching up with 3 different elements on the page and you wish to click the element that contains the text "View as HTML" or maybe you simply want the second element.

let's say this is your Navigator Object is called: someObject

If someObject is matching with 3 elements on the page, you can select the second element by simply typing `someObject[1]`

Navigator Objects that match with more than one page element behave as a list.

If you want to find the element that contains text = "View as HTML", you could do:

```
someObject.find{ element ->
    element.text().contains("View as HTML")
}
```

Like I said, your question is a bit unclear, so I can only hope that this is what you were asking for.